# SQL Server datatype error for various numeric values

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, t-sql

Using SQL Server Import/Export wizard, I am trying to import data from a `.CSV` file into a SQL Server table.

The file has about 3 million records, one column has money value (just the numbers) with number like 126000000000 (that is 126 billion) without comma, and number like 64322.72, and number like -18974.41, etc. These are just numbers with no currency sign or comma.

In the corresponding destination column in the SQL Server table, when I define the type as `numeric(19,4)`, I get the following error at some row:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row # 85954, column 1 (MyColumnName) in data file MyFile.csv.

And, because of the above error, when I change the data type to `bigint`, then, as expected, I get the above error on a row in `csv` file that has 64322.72 value.

And, when I change the data type to `numeric(24,4)`, I get the same error on the exact row # 85954

**Question**: I know since the file has about 3 million records, it will be hard to guess what other types of the number its above mentioned column may have. But, just based on the above described scenarios, if you were to guess/suggest, what would be your suggestion on what data type I may want to try to resolve the data conversion issue described above? Or, are there other suggestion to resolve the issue?

**Remark**: I am using latest versions of Excel and SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Are you able to scan the Excel table for the min and max values? If the file is too large for that, I have also created a dummy staging table in SQL with relaxed column requirements, maybe even varchar() to run a file import. Then I can order and search the data for the outliers before running my final import with correct settings.

Comment: Are you positive there are that all 3 million rows are all numeric?

Comment: idk why SQLServer gives cryptic error message, but that's exactly why I created the **CSV Lint** plugin for Notepad++. You could try validating the csv file using this plugin to check if maybe there is a comma missing (which shifts the column values) or a value not quoted correctly or something https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/

Comment: Could maybe be some readbuffer error, which cuts the last line values in half? Like if the file is too large, and the entire file is cut-off after like 2GB maybe? Or it could also be that the file contains an unreadable character like `\ESC` or even just an extra space like `123.4 `.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE VarcharExample (
    ExampleColumn VARCHAR(100)
)

--- Using three invalid values:
INSERT INTO VarcharExample
VALUES ('20.0000')
    , ('357.500')
    , ('1226.00')
    , ('71.0')
    , ('36987.200000')
    , ('45.16710')
    , ('9645.00')
    , ('Dog')
    , ('$1.00')
    , ('12E33')


;WITH ClearAlphas AS(
    SELECT ExampleColumn
    FROM VarcharExample
    WHERE ExampleColumn NOT LIKE '%[A-za-z$]%'
), ParseNumerics AS (
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(ExampleColumn, CHARINDEX('.', ExampleColumn) - 1) + '.' + SUBSTRING(ExampleColumn,(CHARINDEX('.',ExampleColumn)+1),3) AS DECIMAL(22,8)) CastedNumeric
    FROM ClearAlphas
)
SELECT *
FROM ParseNumerics
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pet peeve - the semi-colon is a statement **terminator**, not a "beginator" to be used as a kludge for lazy coding involving CTEs. Use terminators for every statement.